# Git push master only after given commit

Tags: git, github, git-push

I have a local git project that I would like to open source by pushing to a public Github repo. Let say that this is the local project history:

```
          F-G [feature-1]
         /   \
A-B-C-D-E     H-I-J   [master]
        ^
         \(first public ready commit)
```

However, I have a problem: during prototyping I've hard-coded some sensitive data in. Let's say that up to commit D there's data in the code that I would not like anyone to see.

How can I preserve the change history in my local repo but only publish from `E` onwards?

I'm considering two approaches:

1. Squash the commits before `E`, which would make `E` the initial release.
2. Make some sort of publish branch that would begin a bit later that the `master`.

Command line snippets welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, I'd do it with a graft file and rewriting:

First, tag D and E. I'll assume they can be referred to as D and E from here on.

Now, fake E's history so that it doesn't have a parent:

```
git rev-parse E >.git/info/grafts
```

Then, rewrite the commits to reflect this history:

```
git filter-branch -- --all
```

Now, you have a local tag D that points to the sensitive data, and a local tag E that points to the clean data as the initial commit:

```
  F'-G' [feature-1]
 /     \
E'      H'-I'-J'   [master]

A-B-C-D
```

Now, for your local needs, it may be helpful to have E' show D as the parent again, and this can be done with a graft file again:

```
echo `git rev-parse E` `git rev-parse D` >.git/info/grafts
```

Note that you *don't* want to run `git filter-branch` now.

Locally, your history will look like this:

```
          F'-G' [feature-1]
         /     \
A-B-C-D-E'      H'-I'-J'   [master]
```

but if you push, you'll push the *real* E', which has no parent, so remotely, you'd only get

```
  F'-G' [feature-1]
 /     \
E'      H'-I'-J'   [master]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm leaving @hvd's answer as the accepted one, because awesome.

However, since my particular use case was for removing sensitive data, I've gone with the route outlined in [Githubs guide for just this case](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data). Specifically by using [BFG](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/):

```
cd repo_dir
wget http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/madgag/bfg/1.11.0/bfg-1.11.0.jar
echo "PASSWORD1" >> passwords.txt
echo "KEY_1==>KEY_FOR_SERVICE_1" >> passwords.txt
java -jar bfg-1.11.0.jar --replace-text passwords.txt .
rm passwords.txt
rm bfg-1.11.0.jar
```

That's just a one off for anyone trying to do something similiar, but I definitely will hold on to BFG for the future.